# Cleanly handling /usr/local/ with Swift package manager and libevent

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, swift-package-manager

I have 2 dependencies in my project `libevent` and `libressl`. Both of which are installed locally ( respectively under `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/opt/libressl/include` )

What I am looking for to achieve is for SPM to automatically understand to search in those directories.

I know I can pass flags to swift build to achieve this; but my ultimate goal is that I can properly generate xcode projects from the command line without having to constantly add custom build flags in Xcode.

I'm pretty sure it is possible, since I do not have to enter the custom settings for PostgreSQL.

Swift-tools version is at 4.0.x

Package.swift for reference:

```
// swift-tools-version:4.0
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "CEvent",
    providers: [
        .brew(["libevent"]),
        .apt(["libevent-dev"])
    ],
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries produced by a package, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "CEvent",
            targets: ["CEvent"]),
        ],
    dependencies: [
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "CEvent",
            dependencies: []
        ),
    ]
)
```

Module map:

```
module CEvent [system] {
    header "shim.h"
    link "event"
    export *
}
```

And my current build script ( build.sh ):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/fish
swift build -Xcc -O0 -Xcc -fblocks -Xswiftc -lbcrypt -Xswiftc -I/usr/local/include -Xswiftc -L/usr/local/lib -Xswiftc -ltls -Xswiftc -lcrypto -Xswiftc -lssl -Xswiftc -L/usr/local/opt/postgresql/lib -Xswi$
```

As for the reason that I want this. If I add/update/remove dependencies in swift I want to generate a new xcode project, and not have to fix its settings on respective build machines; as well as apt/ubuntu /usr/lib instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you've found out, and documented in your answer, is a good start but not the full story. Yes, SwiftPM uses `pkg-config` to determine where certain libraries are installed. Yes, SwiftPM uses the `pkgConfig` name which it'll pass on to `pkg-config`. However the search paths are a bit more involved. On macOS it uses the following list as a [base search path](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/84a5bc77681553419b25cc943c68c00d87d5f8db/Sources/Utility/PkgConfig.swift#L50-L53):

- `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`
- `/usr/local/share/pkgconfig`
- `/usr/lib/pkgconfig`
- `/usr/share/pkgconfig`
- [`PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/84a5bc77681553419b25cc943c68c00d87d5f8db/Sources/Utility/PkgConfig.swift#L103-L108)

However SwiftPM doesn't use the `pkg-config` command, but instead parses `.pc` files directly. By setting the `pkgConfig` parameter on your package, it knows what filename to look for in the paths listed above. And, for the example in your answer, the story stops here. If there's a `libevent.pc` file found it [parses that file](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/84a5bc77681553419b25cc943c68c00d87d5f8db/Sources/Utility/PkgConfig.swift#L56-L101), and any flags returned are passed on to the compiler and linker.

However if you were to define package providers, e.g.:

```
providers: [
    .Brew("libsodium"),
    .Apt("libsodium-dev")
]
```

Then SwiftPM adds additional search paths depending on the package provider for the platform it is building for. Continuing the example of macOS, SwiftPM will run `brew --prefix`. If this returns a path, the following path is [added as a additional search path](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/6274ebcb952f89a48dfa6d000d864940d727d9d3/Sources/PackageLoading/Module%2BPkgConfig.swift#L112-L121):

- `[brewPrefix]/opt/[packageName]/lib/pkgconfig`

In my example of `libsodium`, SwiftPM is now able to infer the location of the library without requiring `brew link` or symlinks at all. In my verbose build output it lists the `libsodium` library path in my cellar: `-L/usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.11/lib`.

Comment: Great extra information thanks! It'll sure help me on my future server side swift endevours. Though currently struggling with segfaults in libressl on linux since I made the changes... but that is besides the point. I want to add one quick sidenote, libsodium 1.0.12/13 have been audited. Go update if its on brew!

Answer (score 0):

Alright so the thing I ignored from analysing other projects ( IBM-Swift/CLibpq in particular ) seems to be making use of the tool `pkg-config` which is not something I personally ever touched before.

pkg-config looks in `/usr/lib/pkgconfig` `/usr/share/pkgconfig` and the local variants for config files used in during the build process.

Inside Package.swift, after the `name` parameter you need to insert something for example:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "CEvent",
    pkgConfig: "libevent",
```

Some caveats I discovered with this:

- The bcrypt library I am using does not have a full fletched install or build inside the makefile so I compiled it using the new options found in swift4 PM instead found here: [BCrypt example on github](https://github.com/jabwd/CBCrypt.git) and the Swift docs for more help here: [SPM API Redesign](https://swift.org/blog/swift-package-manager-manifest-api-redesign/)
- LibreSSL found in Homebrew will not install its pkgconfig on the system; so it is easiest or in my eyes best maintenance wise to either manually add it or to compile LibreSSL-portable from source.

Overall great learning experience for me today.