# How do I link to a system module from inside a C language target with Swift Pacakge Manager?

Tags: swift, swift4, swift-package-manager

I want to implement a C wrapper for Bullet physics in Swift.  Basically my plan is to implement a C language target which wraps the necessary functionality I am using in bullet, and to depend on this C target in my swift code.  The problem is, I can't get the bullet headers to be found from within the C language target.

My initial approach has been to create 3 modules managed by Swift Package Manager: a system module (bullet), a C language target (the wrapper) and a Swift module (the client code).

My system module looks like this:

### Package.swift:

```
// swift-tools-version:3.1

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Cbullet",
    pkgConfig: "bullet",
    providers: [
        .Brew("bullet")
    ]
)
```

### module.modulemap:

```
module ClibBullet [system] {
  header "/usr/local/Cellar/bullet/2.86.1_1/include/bullet/btBulletCollisionCommon.h"
  header "/usr/local/Cellar/bullet/2.86.1_1/include/bullet/btBulletDynamicsCommon.h"
  link "bullet"
  export *
}
```

The other two modules are part of the same package:

### Package.swift

```
// swift-tools-version:4.0
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

func localModulesPath(_ moduleName: String) -> String {
    return "../\(moduleName)"
}

let package = Package(
    name: "Physics",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "Physics",
            targets: ["Physics"]),

    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: localModulesPath("Cbullet"), .branch("master")),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "CBulletWrapper",
            dependencies: []),
        .target(
            name: "Physics",
            dependencies: ["CBulletWrapper"]),
    ]
)
```

From inside my `CBulletWrapper.cpp` implementation file, I try to include the Cbullet headers like so:

```
#include <Cbullet/btBulletCollisionCommon.h>
#include <Cbullet/btBulletDynamicsCommon.h>
```

But I get an error:

```
"btBulletCollisionCommon.h" file not found
```

I have also tried including the bullet headers from their explicit path:

```
#include "/usr/local/Cellar/bullet/2.86.1_1/include/bullet/btBulletDynamicsCommon.h"
```

But then I get `file not found` errors on all the imports within `btBulletDynamicsCommon.h` (for example `#include "LinearMath/btVector3.h"`

So the question is, what is the correct way to link to a system library from inside a C language target built by Swift Pacakage Manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Swift Package Manager C Language Target Support Proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0038-swiftpm-c-language-targets.md) under "Proposed Solution":

> 4. If the include directory includes any file named "module.modulemap", then those will be presumed to define the modules for the target, and no module maps will be synthesized.

I think your best bet is to:

1. Add a **module.modulemap** file in the **include** folder of your C language target source folder (CBulletWrapper) that includes the **header** and **link** statements necessary to reference the system (Brew) provided library. Maybe something like:

   ```
   module CBulletWrapper [system] {
       // This is the umbrella header (also in your "include" folder) for your existing wrapper implementation code which itself includes the "bullet" header files
       header "CBulletWrapper.h"

       //Link to the "bullet" library file in the Brew location (absolute path)
       link "/full/path/to/brew/library/libbullet.a"

       //Re-Export all included modules to packages that include this "CBulletWrapper" module 
       export *
   }
   ```
2. Omit your existing external system module (Cbullet) dependency altogether (in your "Physics" package's **Package.swift** file)

Note: AFAIK there is no way to implement the "pkgConfig", "providers" declarations from the "Cbullet" system module package's **Package.swift** in your "Physics" module's **Package.swift** file. It appears that this issue is being addressed in the following proposal: [Package Manager System Library Targets](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0208-package-manager-system-library-targets.md).

I've had some luck recently with this approach. Also, you save the additional effort of maintaining an external system module map package repository (if its not going to be shared with other projects). This makes development MUCH easier if you need to link additional external C libraries to your main "Physics" package later on: Just add another C language target with its own **module.modulemap** and thin/thick wrapper code.

Comment: Is there any alternative to putting the `pkgConfig` declaration in the client package?  It seems like this approach would only work until you want to include multiple system libraries which use pkgConfig.

Comment: Here's a statement on `pkgConfig` from the official [SwiftPM usage](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md):  "The pkgConfig parameter helps SwiftPM in figuring out the include and library search paths for the system library. Note: If you don't want to use the pkgConfig parameter you can pass the path of a directory containing the library using the -L flag in commandline when building your app:

example$ swift build -Xlinker -L/usr/local/lib/

". I don't think `pkgConfig` is necessary if the **module.modulemap** includes absolute paths.

Comment: BUT, I suspect that `pkgConfig` is the right approach going forward and will be more important once swift evolves (officially) beyond Ubuntu.

Comment: More info on `pkgConfig` and `providers` in this question: [Cleanly handling /usr/local/ with Swift package manager and libevent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47096503/cleanly-handling-usr-local-with-swift-package-manager-and-libevent)

Comment: @MikeC. I've done step 1, then tried adding "pkgConfig" and "providers" to Package.swift, but SPM complains that `the 'pkgConfig' property can only be used with a System Module Package`. My system module is in `Sources/CCurl` with modulemap in `Sources/CCurl/include/module.modulemap`. Would appreciate if you could share a sample buildable project.

Comment: @Zmey - I updated my answer. I shouldn't have included the step to move the 'pkgConfig', 'providers' declarations from the system module package. (Try omitting your 'pkgConfig' and 'providers' declarations.) Once this proposal is implemented in a future version of swift a better solution will be to declare your C language targets as 'system library targets': [Package Manager System Library Targets](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0208-package-manager-system-library-targets.md)